# How to get the number of entries in a measurement

Tags: influxdb

I am a newbie to influxdb. I just started to read the influx documentation.

I cant seem to get the equivalent of *'select count(*) from table'* to work in influx db.

I have a measurement called cart:

```
time                status  cartid          
1456116106077429261 0       A
1456116106090573178 0       B
1456116106095765618 0       C
1456116106101532429 0       D
```

but when I try to do

```
select count(cartid) from cart
```

I get the error

```
ERR: statement must have at least one field in select clause
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose cartId is a tag rather than a field value? `count()` currently can't be used on tag and time columns. So if your `status` is a non-tag column (a field), do the count on that.

**EDIT:**

[Reference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/query_language/functions/#count)

Comment: Correct, [InfluxDB functions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/query_language/functions/#count) can only accept fields as arguments, not tags.

Answer (score 6):

This works as long as no field or tag exists with the name `count`:

```
SELECT SUM(count) FROM (SELECT *,count::INTEGER FROM MyMeasurement GROUP BY count FILL(1))
```

If it does use some other name for the `count` field. This works by first selecting all entries including an unpopulated field (`count`) then groups by the unpopulated field which does nothing but allows us to use the fill operator to assign `1` to each entry for `count`. Then we select the sum of the count fields in a super query. The result should look like this:

```
name: MyMeasurement
----------------
time    sum
0       47799
```

It's a bit hacky but it's the only way to guarantee a count of **all** entries when no field exists that is always present in all entries.

Comment: Very useful, here is a simpler version: `SELECT COUNT(x) FROM (SELECT *,x::INTEGER FROM MyMeasurement FILL(0))`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using InfluxDB 2, here are two more options:

### Option 1 - CLI

```
echo 'from(bucket: "primary") |> range(start: 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2030-01-01T00:00:00Z) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "motor") |> count() |> yield(name: "count")' | \
influx query --org=primary -
```

Make sure give a big time range to include all data.

### Option 2 - InfluxDB Data Explorer

```
from(bucket: "primary")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "motor")
  |> count()
  |> yield(name: "count")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from(bucket: "bucketName")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> group(columns: ["_measurement", "_field"])  // Group by measurement and field
  |> count(column: "_value")  // Count the occurrences of each combination of measurement and field
  |> sum(column: "_value")  // Sum the counts to get the total count
```

Flux Query for finding total count of occurrences