# How many points in an InfluxDB measurement?

Tags: count, influxdb

Since there is no way to [delete points by field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685114/delete-points-with-unwanted-field-values-from-influxdb-measurement) in InfluxDB, I'd like to get a count of all the points, SELECT INTO excluding the points with unwanted values, then get a count of the second measurement.

However,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM measurement1
```

returns an array of counts for each field and tag, which doesn't tell me how many data points there are total.

Comment: See my answer to this questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61650101/7144427).

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is currently no way to do this without knowing a name of a column/value that is present in all points.

Although `time` is always present in all points, it is unfortunately not possible to do `count(time)` for now, either.

[This issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/961) addresses the problem, but it is closed and a bit outdated. Someone should open a new one because the problem is still there.

Answer (score -3):

use this command

```
SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY
```

works for tag

Comment: Cardinality isn't directly related to the number of data points in a measurement. You could have a trillion data points and a cardinality of 1.